# Insert execSql не работает

Tags: android

не получается сделать insert, база почему-то всегда пустая

```
public class CitiesHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cities";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_REGION= "region";
    private static final String TABLE_CITY= "city";
    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_REGION_ID = "region_id";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone_code";

    public CitiesHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String strRegion="CREATE TABLE region (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(strRegion);
        String insertRegion="INSERT INTO region Values   (1, 'АР Крым') , (2, 'Винницкая область') , (3, 'Волынская область') , (4, 'Днепропетровская область') , (5, 'Донецкая область') , (6, 'Житомирская область') , (7, 'Закарпатская область') , (8, 'Запорожская область') , (9, 'Ивано-Франковская область') , (10, 'Киевская область') , (11, 'Кировоградская область') , (12, 'Луганская область') , (13, 'Львовская область') , (14, 'Николаевская область') , (15, 'Одесская область') , (16, 'Полтавская область') , (17, 'Ровенская область') , (18, 'Сумская область') , (19, 'Тернопольская область') , (20, 'Харьковская область') , (21, 'Херсонская область') , (22, 'Хмельницкая область') , (23, 'Черкасская область') , (24, 'Черниговская область') , (25, 'Черновицкая область')";
        db.execSQL(insertRegion);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CITY);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_REGION);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public String[] getRegions(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGION;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        String [] regions;
        regions=new String[user.values().size()];
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : user.entrySet()) {
            int i=0;
            regions[i] = entry.getValue();      
            i++;
        }
        // return user
        return regions;
    }

    public int getRegionID(String name){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGION+" WHERE name="+name;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("id", cursor.getString(0));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return Integer.valueOf(user.get("id"));
    }

    public String[] getCities(int region_id){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CITY+" WHERE region_id="+String.valueOf(region_id);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        String [] cities;
        cities=new String[user.values().size()];
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : user.entrySet()) {
            int i=0;
            cities[i] = entry.getValue();       
            i++;
        }
        // return user
        return cities;
    }

}
```

да, я читал в документации, что надо использовать для INSERT db.insert(..) но у меня есть большой sql файл, и поэтому мне удобно execSQL, но почему-то не получается.

Таким образом будет неудобно. С областями ладно, но у меня там еще 5000 городов. если я буду делать так:

```
ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
insertValues.put("name", "Рени");
db.insert("region", null, insertValues);
то єто глупая и долгая работа
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String insertRegion="INSERT INTO region Values   (1, 'АР Крым') , (2, 'Винницкая область') , (3, 'Волынская область') , (4, 'Днепропетровская область') , (5, 'Донецкая область') , (6, 'Житомирская область') , (7, 'Закарпатская область') , (8, 'Запорожская область') , (9, 'Ивано-Франковская область') , (10, 'Киевская область') , (11, 'Кировоградская область') , (12, 'Луганская область') , (13, 'Львовская область') , (14, 'Николаевская область') , (15, 'Одесская область') , (16, 'Полтавская область') , (17, 'Ровенская область') , (18, 'Сумская область') , (19, 'Тернопольская область') , (20, 'Харьковская область') , (21, 'Херсонская область') , (22, 'Хмельницкая область') , (23, 'Черкасская область') , (24, 'Черниговская область') , (25, 'Черновицкая область')";
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(insertRegion);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    db.close(); `введите код здесь`
```

Comment: получилось

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй rawQuery вместо execSQL, если я правильно понимаю

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

то  возможно все дело в том что он не воспринимает строку как один запрос ... не уверен но мало ли

Answer (score 1):

```
String strRegion="CREATE TABLE region (id PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT)";
```

А тип  INTEGER  не надо идентификатору задавать? Не думаю, что в этом дело, но всё же.

p.s. и всё же советую работать с методами хелпера:  db.insert(..) и прочими.

Comment: нет, дело не в єтом. это я пропустил когда копировал сюда код. но вообще я тестил с INT